# documentInteractionController didEndSendingToApplication not being called. File not being transferred

Tags: ios, swift3, uidocumentinteraction

Having issues with my `UIDocumentInteractionController`. I am trying to handle unsupported file types by transferring to apps that support them. Below is my relevant code.

```
 class AttachmentsView: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {

 var docController: UIDocumentInteractionController!


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        switch filetype {

        case: .image:
        return

        case: .document:
        return

        case: .audio:
        return

        case: .video:
        return

        case .unknown:
        let unknownFile = files[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item]

        guard let fileURL = unknownFile.fullPath else {

            return
        }

        self.docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: fileURL)
        self.docController.delegate = self
        self.docController.url = fileURL

        self.docController.presentOpenInMenu(from: (superview?.frame)!, in: self, animated: true)
        return
 }
}
```

Here is what my `fileURL` looks like -

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1E67D26D-B9FE-4455-8D30-6A4FED07071E/tmp/folder_attachments/a9500123-c5e6-469b-8867-af72050f453e/1b177057-c507-445a-a8a0-b7b349ae79c6.zip
```

In this example it's a .zip file. The `UIDocumentInteractionController` comes up just fine as an activity sheet type view. Shows AirDrop, Add to Notes, Add to Health, Import with Dropbox and a few more. I can also add to iCloud drive.

When I tap on the Dropbox option, It goes through:

```
func documentInteractionController(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController, willBeginSendingToApplication application: String?) {
    print("begin sending")
}
```

But does not go through:

```
func documentInteractionController(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController, didEndSendingToApplication application: String?) {
    print("completed")
}
```

Another hint is when I tap AirDrop I get `Error = "Error Domain=SFOperation Code=-5 \"The transfer failed because you tried to send an invalid file.\"`

Any idea why this might be happening? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Your file path shows the answer: you've built the path in a wrong way, so it points to the private area. You can use Bundle's `pathForResource` approach to make sure the file path is valid, or build the path starting with e.g. `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`, converting it to URL (using `URL(fileURLWithPath: folderPath)`) and then appending components using `appendingPathComponent`.